# prevent firefox from flashing white on loading page

Tags: firefox, load, userchrome.css

How can I prevent Firefox from flashing a white page before it loads a webpage?  I often use dark themes with Firefox (with the Stylus extension), and it is annoying to see a white flash before it loads the dark webpage.  Is there some way to change the loading page background color to some other color such as black or dark grey?'

I have seen several webpages that claim to have the solution.  However, whenever I try those solutions, they never seem to work.  What is the solution with the current most up-to-date version of Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

The most effective way to get rid of this;

Open Firefox settings, search for Color (in the language you have firefox set). Click the Color button and uncheck "use system colors".

Close all firefox windows, then reopen.

Comment: To add to this: looking for "color" I didn't find the right button, apparently I'd set it to UK English and "colour" worked. Then, seeing "use system colours" already unchecked, I figured setting the text and background colours there to something light and dark might work - and it did! No more flashes = happy me :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `about:config` and accept the warning message
2. Set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to **true**
3. Create a userChrome.css file according to these instructions: https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html
4. Paste the following into `userChrome.css`

```
#browser vbox#appcontent tabbrowser, #content, #tabbrowser-tabpanels, browser[type=content-primary], browser[type=content] > html { background: #222 !important; }
```

5. Paste the following into `userContent.css`:

```
/* dark blank tab */
@-moz-document url(about:blank), url(about:newtab) {
    #newtab-window, html:not(#ublock0-epicker) {
        background: #222 !important;
    }
}
```

Source: cml-99 via [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/h9ca8e/eliminate_white_page_splash_when_loading_page/fuvy077)